# Trouble with ajax (PHP and Javascript) - how to transfer properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm having big trouble with the ajax function inside the jquery library. I am a complete beginner to jQuery, ajax and php, but I am working on this school project, which is supposed to be a game (kind of), where the page creates a 10x10 table, fills it with numbers and automatically picks one of the cells, and then the user gets to guess which cell it is.

Under the table, there is a textarea, in which I am supposed to output the progress of the game; for instance, "Wrong guess! Number of guesses: 1; Distance to the correct cell: 3", etc...

The problem is in implementation; I have two .php files, one being the main site on which the game is played, and the other one being the statistic part (just mathemathics and stuff).

Without further ado, here are my codes:

The code of the main .php file in which the game is played:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
        $("#tablezz td").click(function() 
        {    
            var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );
            var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() );   
            var dat = { column: column_num, row: row_num };

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: dat,
                    url: "preveri.php",//this is the name of the mathemathical .php file
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#imamonkey").prepend(data);
                    }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo "<table id='tablezz' border='1'>";
    $counter=1;
    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
        echo"<tr>";
        for($j=0; $j<10; $j++){
            echo "<td> $counter </td>"    ;
            $counter=$counter+1;
        }
    }
    echo"</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["rightx"] = rand(1,10);
    $_SESSION["righty"] = rand(1,10);
    echo"<br>
    <br>
    <textarea id='imamonkey' rows='30' cols='46'></textarea>";
    ?>
</body>
```

And the code of the other, mathemathical .php file;

```
<?php

$distance=sqrt((($_GET["column"] - $_SESSION["rightx"]) * ($_GET["column"] - $_SESSION["rightx"])) + (($_GET["row"] - $_SESSION["righty"]) * ($_GET["row"] - $_SESSION["righty"])));

if(isset($_SESSION["tries"])) {
$_SESSION["tries"]=$_SESSION["tries"]+1;    
}
else {
$_SESSION["tries"]=1;
}


if($_SESSION["rightx"]==$_GET["column"] && $_SESSION["righty"]==$_GET["row"]) { 
echo "Gooes guess. This took you $_SESSION['tries'] tries." 
}
else {
echo "Bad call! The distance to the right cell is: $distance . So far you've tried $_SESSION['tries'] times.";
}

?>
```

The only trouble in this is, that my ajax function is apparently not working properly. When I click on a `<td>` cell to test it, it inserts blank stuff into the textarea. I must've done something wrong with the data and dat, but I am completely clueless what it would be. How do I make it insert the echos from the other .php file for example?

Any help is MUCH appreciated as I am completely clueless what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance, *BG*

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: No, how do I do that? I am using google chrome. (sorry kinda newbie to web programming)

Comment: `F12`will reveal all sorts of data about what is going on with your browser, including requests, responses, connections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have below errors in your code :

1. Session must start in the beginning.
2. Fixed for syntax error.
3. Also session must start in second page.

Try below script:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
        $("#tablezz td").click(function() 
        {    
            var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );
            var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() );   
            var dat = { column: column_num, row: row_num };

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: dat,
                    url: "preveri.php",//this is the name of the mathemathical .php file
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#imamonkey").prepend(data);
                    }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo "<table id='tablezz' border='1'>";
    $counter=1;
    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
        echo"<tr>";
        for($j=0; $j<10; $j++){
            echo "<td> $counter </td>"    ;
            $counter=$counter+1;
        }
    }
    echo"</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    $_SESSION["rightx"] = rand(1,10);
    $_SESSION["righty"] = rand(1,10);
    echo"<br>
    <br>
    <textarea id='imamonkey' rows='30' cols='46'></textarea>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And second page :

```
<?php
session_start();
$distance=sqrt((($_GET["column"] - $_SESSION["rightx"]) * ($_GET["column"] - $_SESSION["rightx"])) + (($_GET["row"] - $_SESSION["righty"]) * ($_GET["row"] - $_SESSION["righty"])));

if(isset($_SESSION["tries"])) {
    $_SESSION["tries"]=$_SESSION["tries"]+1;
}
else {
    $_SESSION["tries"]=1;
}

if($_SESSION["rightx"]==$_GET["column"] && $_SESSION["righty"]==$_GET["row"]) {
    echo "Gooes guess. This took you ".$_SESSION['tries']." tries." ;
}
else {
    echo "Bad call! The distance to the right cell is: ".$distance." . So far you've tried ".$_SESSION['tries']." times.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help AnkiiG. :)  

Sadly however, this has fixed nothing; I never got any syntax errors earlier , or any undefined variables (or wrong session start) so I don't think that was the issue.

Any other ideas what could've been causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call you're trying to prepend data to a textarea:

```
$("#imamonkey").prepend(data);
```

This means that the data is placed *before* the textarea in the DOM (you may actually be able to see the data if you look at the updated information in your browser's console). What you want to do is place the data *in* the textarea:

```
 $("#imamonkey").val(data);
```

In your PHP file you need to add `session_start();` to the beginning of the file *and* any file in which you expect to use session data such as your HTML file.